# Can we detect and track facial Landmarks using features2d from openCV?

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I need to make a Fast Localization of Facial Landmark using openCV for Android. I am new to openCV and I was wondering if features2d can be used from openCV library for this purpose rather than using dlib or other libraries. If yes then which Feature Detector(eg: SIFT,SURF,ORBetc) will give a good result for just facial landmarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these will be particularly accurate. Try [FaceTracker](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker) from Jason Saragih. It is easy to unbox and has Android and iOS ports.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will try that.

Comment: Also is there a way I can make my own facial landmark tracker using just openCV library?

Comment: @Pragyan93, Probably not easily.